# Converting assembly code to C code

Tags: assembly, disassembly

What process can be used to convert assembly code into equivalent C code? What kind of tools can be leveraged for higher result accuracy?

Comment: Yes, there is.  Was that all you wanted to know?  Or was there more to your question?

Comment: "<<assembly code>>" is not a question! And your description is not much better. This is not a forum! EDIT* Much better :)

Comment: He might want a term to google for so he can find it...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560344/how-does-one-disassemble-proc-c-programs

Comment: yeah, that's all i wanted. can U tell me the name of the software? thx

Comment: @Brian: "U"?  "thx"?  What are those words?  Please continue to **update** your question to clarify whatever it is you're looking for.  Please **fix** your question.

Comment: **while searching:** It's called reverse engineering. Pretty straight-forward and the converter tool is the brain.

Comment: If its not reverse engineering related, then is a possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376856/convert-asm-to-c-not-reverse-engineer

Comment: What you are probably looking for is a Decompiler. Now usually, decompilers aren't able to rebuild the original source files and some outputs might even be unintelligible.

To ensure a better outcome, compile your program with debugging information (the `-g` flag with the `g++` compiler). You may still have to put in a lot of manual labor reversing the code.

Snowman, Boomerang, IDA Pro are some tools/

Answer (score 6):

You cannot go backward to the original C but can do a static binary translation into C that is equivalent to the machine instruction.

Answer (score 4):

[Wiki Link to disassemblers](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Disassemblers_and_Decompilers)

Comment: I need a software to convert assembly code to C, not machine code to assembly codes. thx.

Comment: @Brian: Please actually read the actual link actually provided.  Decompilers are on that page also.

Answer (score 3):

The term you are looking for is 'decompiler'.  Check here for a discussion:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Disassemblers_and_Decompilers#Decompilers

Answer (score 1):

I used **IDAPro** in the past and it does a pretty good job doing what you need.

Check it out.

http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/

Comment: IDA is just the disassembler, not a decompiler, for that you'd also need the hexrays plugin.

Answer (score -1):

If you have an entire application originally written in Assembly, you could look for an automated tool that can convert the entire code base. One that does Assembler conversions that might want to take a look at is [Datatek](http://datatek-net.com/conversions/asm.php):

> Datatek has developed a sophisticated tool-set and a highly
>   customizable process for the automated conversion of Assembler to
>   high-level languages such as C, C++, COBOL, C#, Java, etc.

*Full disclosure: I work for Datatek, and personally think we provide a useful service.*

Comment: I would have probably disclosed in your post that you are affiliated with Datatek (your profile does).

Comment: @MichaelPetch You're right, my mistake.